# How to get configurable option on custom module

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, custom

I want to display all configurable options same as details page in my custom module.

It should work like product details page(like below image) . any one have any idea ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this tutorial it may be help you `https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-configurable-product-magento-2.html`

Comment: i want that programatically

Comment: Did you get solution for this ? If yes than share with us!! Thanks